Can someone explain this mapping notation (with reference to partial differential equations)?
The quoted text below is from Partial Differential Equations by Evans. Can anyone explain the mapping notation (Cartesian product) in the context given below?

A partial differential equation (PDE) is an equation involving an
unknown function of two or more variables and certain of its partial
derivatives.
Using the notation explained in Appendix A, we can write out
symbolically a typical PDE, as follows. Fix an integer $k \geq 1$ and
let $U$ denote an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
DEFINITION. An expression of the form $$ F\left(D^k u(x), D^{k-1}
 u(x), \ldots, D u(x), u(x), x\right)=0 \quad(x \in U) $$ is called a
$k^{\text {th }}$-order partial differential equation, where $$ F:
 \mathbb{R}^{n^k} \times \mathbb{R}^{n^{k-1}} \times \cdots \times
\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ is
given, and $$ u: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ is the unknown.

What is meant by $\mathbb{R}^{n^k}$ i.e., why $n^k$? For a two-variable, second order PDE ($k$=2), it appears that it will be $\mathbb{R}^{2^2}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, but there will be three unique second partial derivatives not four.

Why do you assume all the second order partial derivatives are continuous?  If they're not, $u_{12} \neq u_{21}$ is possible.

I am not a mathematician but a chemist rather, I was exploring this book. So is this a highly generalized statement?

It is.  There are $n^k$ derivatives of order $k$ in $n$ variables if we assume the order of differentiation matters -- $n$ choices for the first variable, $n$ choices for the second variable, ..., $n$ choices for the $k^{\text{th}}$ variable.  One may seek solutions that have continuous derivatives of some order and may or may not find any.  If not, one may be forced to relax the continuity and check which derivatives don't simplify together any more.

Another way to think of it is the derivative of a scalar field is a vector of size $n$, the second derivative is a matrix of size $n\times n$, the third will be a tensor of size $n\times n\times n$. This just keeps track of that pattern
